# Sharetribe - redirection to projectname.lvh.me and 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby, sharetribe

I installed Sharetribe on my server. On IP address with 3000 port I had configuration form. When I tried to save, I had redirection to projectname.lvh.me:3000 and error that this site isn't existing. Now I have 500 Internal Server Error error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please post the relevant entries from your log file, your routes and the controller action code.

Comment: How can I check routes and controller action code?

Comment: Please add more details about the code, controller actions an also logs referring to stacktrace

Answer (score -1):

```
Log file:

`# Logfile created on 2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 by logger.rb/56438
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent version 4.2.0.334 in "production" environment.
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simpenter code herely (25549)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEW_RELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=false environment variable or modify the "production" section of your newrelic.yml.
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml (/sharetribe)
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] WARN : Agent is configured not to use SSL when communicating with New Relic's servers
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing Memcache instrumentation for dalli gem
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing ActiveJob instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing Rails 3+ middleware instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord 5 instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack::Builder instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing Rack::Builder middleware instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation [part 1/2]
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing Redis Instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 view instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Controller instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Action Cable instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation [part 2/2]
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent version 4.2.0.334 in "production" environment.
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEW_RELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=false environment variable or modify the "production" section of your newrelic.yml.
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml (/sharetribe)
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Environment: production
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Dispatcher: delayed_job
[2018-08-17 11:24:58 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Application: Sharetribe
[2018-08-17 11:25:02 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/21154/applications/854556
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent version 4.2.0.334 in "production" environment.
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEW_RELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=false environment variable or modify the "production" section of your newrelic.yml.
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml (/sharetribe)
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] WARN : Agent is configured not to use SSL when communicating with New Relic's servers
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Environment: production
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Dispatcher: webrick
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Application: Sharetribe
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler not available: No DJ worker present. Skipping DJ queue sampler
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing Memcache instrumentation for dalli gem
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing ActiveJob instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing Rails 3+ middleware instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord 5 instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack::Builder instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing Rack::Builder middleware instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation [part 1/2]
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing Redis Instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 view instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Controller instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Action Cable instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:28:27 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:28:29 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Doing deferred dependency-detection before Rack startup
[2018-08-17 11:28:29 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/21154/applications/854556
[2018-08-17 11:31:43 -0400 simply (25549)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
[2018-08-17 11:52:38 -0400 simply (25921)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
[2018-08-17 11:52:38 -0400 simply (25921)] ERROR : 1 error(s) running task for event 'report_event_data' in Agent Event Loop:
[2018-08-17 11:52:38 -0400 simply (25921)] ERROR : NewRelic::Agent::ServerConnectionException: Recoverable error connecting to collector-255.newrelic.com:80 after 0.000386102 seconds: Failed to open TCP connection to collector-255.newrelic.com:80 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution)
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent version 4.2.0.334 in "production" environment.
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEW_RELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=false environment variable or modify the "production" section of your newrelic.yml.
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml (/sharetribe)
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] WARN : Agent is configured not to use SSL when communicating with New Relic's servers
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Environment: production
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Dispatcher: webrick
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Application: Sharetribe
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler not available: No DJ worker present. Skipping DJ queue sampler
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing Memcache instrumentation for dalli gem
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing ActiveJob instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing Rails 3+ middleware instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord 5 instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack::Builder instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing Rack::Builder middleware instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation [part 1/2]
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing Redis Instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 view instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Controller instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Action Cable instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:54:06 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
[2018-08-17 11:54:07 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Doing deferred dependency-detection before Rack startup
[2018-08-17 11:54:08 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/21154/applications/854556
[2018-08-17 12:12:44 -0400 simply (825)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent version 4.2.0.334 in "production" environment.
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEW_RELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=false environment variable or modify the "production" section of your newrelic.yml.
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml (/sharetribe)
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] WARN : Agent is configured not to use SSL when communicating with New Relic's servers
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Environment: production
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Dispatcher: webrick
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Application: Sharetribe
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler not available: No DJ worker present. Skipping DJ queue sampler
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing Memcache instrumentation for dalli gem
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing ActiveJob instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing Rails 3+ middleware instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord 5 instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack::Builder instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing Rack::Builder middleware instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation [part 1/2]
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing Redis Instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 view instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Controller instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Action Cable instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:15:31 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:15:33 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Doing deferred dependency-detection before Rack startup
[2018-08-17 12:15:33 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/21154/applications/854556
[2018-08-17 12:46:15 -0400 simply (953)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent version 4.2.0.334 in "production" environment.
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEW_RELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=false environment variable or modify the "production" section of your newrelic.yml.
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml (/sharetribe)
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] WARN : Agent is configured not to use SSL when communicating with New Relic's servers
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Environment: production
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Dispatcher: webrick
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Application: Sharetribe
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler not available: No DJ worker present. Skipping DJ queue sampler
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing Memcache instrumentation for dalli gem
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing ActiveJob instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing Rails 3+ middleware instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord 5 instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack::Builder instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing Rack::Builder middleware instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation [part 1/2]
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing Redis Instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 view instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Controller instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Action Cable instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:48:02 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
[2018-08-17 12:48:03 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Doing deferred dependency-detection before Rack startup
[2018-08-17 12:48:04 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/21154/applications/854556
[2018-08-17 14:59:18 -0400 simply (1445)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
`
```

Comment: This log does not have anything related to error mentioned in question

Comment: Also extra details like logs etc should not be posted in answer to question. They should be updated in question itself